# ReactJS does not render anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I have this simple code to test if react works but for whatever reason it does not render anything.
I've no idea what the problem is.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="root"></div>


  <script type = "text/babel">

    ReactDOM.render(<p>'test'</p>, document.getElementById("root"));
  
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here in the Stackoverflow snippet, if you enable the "Use BabelJS / ES2015" button it will work as expected, and render the `'test'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use babel in the browser you need to load it.

Add the following script just before the react one.

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Please refer to the documentation https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone

Comment: Thank you... I was really lost, like for an hour I wanted to code something in React, because I am working on some React courses, but the lector did not use this code in it and it worked for him for some reason.